# How to achieve highest performance with multiple USB 3 drives but only one USB 3 port

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3, usb-2

If a computer has one USB 3 port, and one USB 2 port, and the user needs to connect two external USB 3 drives (backwards compatible to USB 2), will highest speeds be obtained if the user connects them both through a multiplexer attached to the USB 3 port, or if one is attached to the USB 2 port and the other to the USB 3 port?

Data will be transferred from the internal hard drive to both external drives, as well as between the two external USB3 drives.

Comment: @davidbaumann Your answer is helpful (thank you), but it doesn't really explain why connecting both drives to a multiplexer would be faster, especially given that it will be limited by a single bus instead of dividing the loads onto two buses.  If you find my question to be interesting, an upvote may be appropriate. ;)

Comment: Actually, as the two drives cannot max out USB 3.0, it's better to connect both to a USB3 port. If you connect one to a USB2.0 port, this drive will stuck at 40 MByte/s.

Answer (score 2):

As USB 3.0 should be able to transfer around 400 MB/s [1], it should be faster to connect both drives to the USB3.

You won't exceed 2x200 MB/s with the harddrives, I am quite sure. For even coming close to this, you would have to copy one very big file to the other harddrive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.0